# Using sessionFactory.openSession idles when saving domain using WL datasource

Tags: grails, weblogic12c, sessionfactory

I have an application which requires to execute a batch insert into 5 tables:
ParentTable, ChildATable, ChildBTable, ParentHistoryTable, Child_A_B_HistoryTable; on ChildATable, ChildBTable and Child_A_B_HistoryTable can contain up to 50k records each.

It is a Grails 2.4.4 application, and in our Development environment, we use the grails configuration file to define the datasource (we are using DB2).

In order to improve our performance, the insert of the child records are performed as:

```
def session = sessionFactory.openSession()
def tx = session.beingTransaction()
```

then we iterate over the childs and use the session to persist the values and flush every 20 records:

```
session.save(obj)
if(count mod 20 == 0){
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
}
```

Once we are done on the loop, commit the transaction and close the session.

```
tx.commit()
and session.close()
```

Now, when getting ready for our production deployment, we are required to define the datasource as part of our WL configuration and consume it using jndi.

For other interactions with the database where we use GORM normally, everything works the same on both dev and prod environments, however for that specific usage of the session, after executing the first call to the session.save(obj) line, the app gets idle.

Any direction or help on this scenario will be highly appreciated.

Regards, Josue Ortiz

Comment: You should do a thread dump to see where the app is stuck.